# Laravel query contains `where exists ( select ....)`

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have an `many to many` and try to query data by two conditions.
The first verify the `station_code` in table `station` and the second is a `like` condition in on column `name` in table `Products`

```
$stationListWithProducts = Station::with('products')
  ->where('station_code', '=', $stationCode)
  ->whereRelation('products', 'name', 'like', '%Price%');
```

If i execute `toRawSql()`  the query is

```
select * from `stations` where `station_code` = 'device-A' and exists 
(select * from ... where ... and `name` like '%Price%')
```

What's confusing me is, that `and existis` in the query.
I've expect that the `whereRelation` add a join and add the condition to my query, not an `exists` condition, which contains a the condition.

How can create the query with a condition on both tables, an what is wrong of my point of view?

Comment: The difference between the join and exists is that the former might result in (unwanted) duplication in the result set, whereas exists logic will not.  Which one you want depends on your goal.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, i'm total agree with you. But  in the php-doc of `whereRelation` there is the information `Add a basic where clause to a relationship query` what means to me, that there should be also a join and a  `and`-Condition with `and 'name' like '%Price%'` addend on the first select.

Comment: There is a `join()` function in Laravel, right?  Why can't you use that?

Comment: I know what you mean, but there is the relation between  `stations` and `products`, and there should be a join or eloquent should know it, because there is the `belongsToMany` relation. You known what i mean?

Comment: `where('x','y')` adds the condition on the `Station` model and `whereRelation('products','x','y')` adds the condition on the related table. Whether it uses an `exists` or `join` internally doesn't matter does it? I'm not sure I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found my problem. I've just requested the `Station` model.
Now it's clear to me. After add the `where` condition, i've to keep on working on the relation and fetch the data from there.

Now the query is correct, an the data too. :)

```
Station::firstWhere('station_code', '=', $stationCode)
            ->products()
            ->where('name', 'like', "%$filterValue%")
            ->get();
```

Comment: this doesn't get you ALL products of `name = $name` that have a station with `code = $code`